# kinectで青玉の認識をopencvを使って行いたいです

Tags: opencv, kinect

エラーメッセージ

```
mainの戻り値の型にはintを使用してくださいvoidは使用できません。
int main(void) オーバーロード関数はint main(void)と戻り値の型のみが異なります
```

この２つがどうしても消えません
よろしくお願いいたします

引用元：http://kivantium.hateblo.jp/entry/20120822/p1
　　　　Kinect 実践プログラム　杉浦司

```c
#include"stdafx.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include "opencv/Labeling.h"
#include <cstdio>

void main()
{
    try {
        KinectSample kinect;
        kinect.initialize();
        kinect.run();
        using namespace cv;
        using namespace std;
        int num;
        int main(); {
            try {
                VideoCapture capture(0);
                Mat RGBMap, Cloud, valid;
                IplImage ipl_RGB;
                IplImage *imgR, *imgG = 0, *imgB;
                IplImage *imgThreshold_R, *imgThreshold_G, *imgThreshold_B, *imgResult, *imgTmp, *RGB_image;
                int x, y;
                short *dst;
                LabelingBS labeling;
                RegionInfoBS    *ri;
                dst = new short[640 * 480];

                imgThreshold_R = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                imgThreshold_G = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                imgThreshold_B = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                imgResult = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                imgTmp = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                imgR = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); //Red
                imgG = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); //Green
                imgB = cvCreateImage(cvSize(640, 480), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); //Blue
                while (1) {
                    // データの更新を待つ
                    capture.grab();
                    // RGBを取得して表示
                    capture.retrieve(RGBMap, CV_CAP_OPENNI_BGR_IMAGE);
                    ipl_RGB = RGBMap;
                    RGB_image = &ipl_RGB;
                    cvSplit(RGB_image, imgB, imgG, imgR, NULL);
                    // 赤の要素が100以上で、緑と青より1.5倍以上あるピクセルを抽出
                    cvThreshold(imgB, imgThreshold_B, 100, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
                    cvDiv(imgB, imgG, imgTmp, 10); // 10倍
                    cvThreshold(imgTmp, imgThreshold_G, 18, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
                    cvDiv(imgB, imgR, imgTmp, 10);
                    cvThreshold(imgTmp, imgThreshold_R, 18, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
                    cvAnd(imgThreshold_G, imgThreshold_R, imgTmp, NULL);
                    cvAnd(imgTmp, imgThreshold_B, imgResult, NULL);
                    cvAnd(imgThreshold_G, imgThreshold_R, imgTmp, NULL);
                    cvAnd(imgTmp, imgThreshold_B, imgResult, NULL);

                    //ラベリング
                    labeling.Exec((uchar *)imgResult->imageData, dst, imgResult->width, imgResult->height, true, 30);
                    if (labeling.GetNumOfResultRegions() != 0) {
                        ri = labeling.GetResultRegionInfo(0);
                        //四角形の描画
                        int ltop_x, ltop_y, rbottom_x, rbottom_y;
                        ri->GetMin(ltop_x, ltop_y);
                        ri->GetMax(rbottom_x, rbottom_y);
                        cvLine(RGB_image, cvPoint(ltop_x, ltop_y), cvPoint(rbottom_x, ltop_y), CV_RGB(255, 255, 255));
                        cvLine(RGB_image, cvPoint(rbottom_x, ltop_y), cvPoint(rbottom_x, rbottom_y), CV_RGB(255, 255, 255));
                        cvLine(RGB_image, cvPoint(rbottom_x, rbottom_y), cvPoint(ltop_x, rbottom_y), CV_RGB(255, 255, 255));
                        cvLine(RGB_image, cvPoint(ltop_x, rbottom_y), cvPoint(ltop_x, ltop_y), CV_RGB(255, 255, 255));
                        float f_x, f_y;
                        ri->GetCenter(f_x, f_y);
                        x = (int)f_x;
                        y = (int)f_y;
                        capture.retrieve(Cloud, CV_CAP_OPENNI_POINT_CLOUD_MAP);
                        capture.retrieve(valid, CV_CAP_OPENNI_VALID_DEPTH_MASK);
                        if (valid.at<unsigned char>(y, x) == 0xff) {
                            Vec3f s = Cloud.at<Vec3f>(y, x);
                            printf("%f %f %f\n", s[0], s[1], s[2]);  //座標を表示
                        }
                        else {
                            printf("invalid!\n");
                        }
                    }

                    cvShowImage("Window", RGB_image);
                    if (waitKey(10) >= 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                destroyAllWindows();
            }
            catch (...) {
                cout << "exception!!" << endl;
            }
        }
    }

    catch (std::exception& ex) {
        std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

main関数の書き方が間違っています。

まずmain関数を

```cpp
void main()
{
  try {
    KinectSample kinect;
    kinect.initialize();
    kinect.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& ex) {
    std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

のように書き換えてください。

青玉を認識するコードを`run()`関数の中に記述します。処理の流れは

- 入力画像をHSV形式に変換する
- 画像の青い部分を抽出する
- 抽出した画像の連結成分を取り出す

という感じです。連結成分を取り出す際にはOpenCVの`connectedComponentsWithStats()`関数（[ドキュメント](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#connectedcomponents)）を使うことをおすすめします。この関数はOpenCV 3.0以降でしか使えないので必要であれば新しいバージョンのOpenCVをインストールしてください。

青玉の認識を行う`run()`関数の例を示します。

```cpp
void run()
{
  cv::Mat image;

  //メインループ
  while (1) {

    //データの更新を待つ
    DWORD ret = ::WaitForSingleObject(streamEvent, INFINITE);
    ::ResetEvent(streamEvent);

    drawRgbImage(image);

    cv::Mat h_image;
    cv::flip(image, h_image, 1);

    // RGB画像をHSV画像に変換
    cv::Mat hsv, extracted;
    cv::cvtColor(h_image, hsv, CV_RGB2HSV); // カメラ画像がBGRの場合はCV_BGR2HSV
    // 色が100<=H<=120, 80<=S<=255, 80<=V<=255の範囲の部分を抽出する
    // 色の範囲は抽出したい物体の色に合わせて調整する
    cv::Scalar hsv_min = cv::Scalar(100, 80, 80);
    cv::Scalar hsv_max = cv::Scalar(120, 255, 255);
    cv::inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max, extracted);

    // ラベリング実行
    cv::Mat labelImg, stats, centroids;
    int nLabels = cv::connectedComponentsWithStats(extracted, labelImg, stats, centroids);

    // 長方形の描画
    for (int i = 1; i < nLabels; ++i) {
      int *param = stats.ptr<int>(i);

      int x = param[0];
      int y = param[1];
      int width = param[2];
      int height = param[3];

      /* C++11の場合はこう書いたほうが分かりやすい
         int x = param[cv::ConnectedComponentsTypes::CC_STAT_LEFT];
         int y = param[cv::ConnectedComponentsTypes::CC_STAT_TOP];
         int width = param[cv::ConnectedComponentsTypes::CC_STAT_WIDTH];
         int height = param[cv::ConnectedComponentsTypes::CC_STAT_HEIGHT];
       */

      cv::rectangle(h_image, cv::Rect(x, y, width, height), cv::Scalar(255, 255, 255), 2);
    }

    //画像を表示する
    cv::imshow("kinect Sample", h_image);

    //終了のためのキー入力チェック兼、表示のためのウェイト
    int key = cv::waitKey(10);
    if (key == 'q') {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

青色の範囲は自分で調整してみてください。

参考

- [OpenCVによる特定色画素の抽出(RGB vs HSV)](http://tecsingularity.com/opencv/colorextraction/)
- [使っている人いるのかな？OpenCV3.0から入ったラべリング処理について](https://qiita.com/wakaba130/items/9d921b8b3eb812e4f197)

Comment: ありがとうございます　色認識行えました！

Comment: @あおき もし問題が解決した場合には、回答の「承認」をしてあげてください。もし未解決で困ったままなら、コメントや質問本文の編集でフォローアップをお願いします。 - 参考: [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)